# How to monitor CPU usage on a device running embedded Linux and BusyBox?

Tags: cpu-usage, monitoring, busybox

I recently began working with a device that uses embedded Linux and BusyBox.  It is very stripped down, and does not have *iostat* or *sar*.  It also doesn't have *dpkg* or *apt* for package management.  The system is a development black-box under a non-disclosure agreement, O.S. version info is:

```
Linux localhost 2.6.34 #1 SMP Fri Sep 14 10:12:23 EDT 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I'd like to monitor system resources, particularly CPU and memory usage, and am wondering how to do this.  It appears that the only command available through BusyBox is *top*, and I'd like other alternatives.

I guess I could cross-compile *sar* on my Windows development system and somehow copy it over, but I've never done that... however, am willing to give it a try if that's my best option, so tips in that area would be appreciated.

Edit: After reading [Linux Implementation of SAR](http://www.softpanorama.org/Admin/Monitoring/Sar/linux_implementation_of_sar.shtml), it appears I wouldn't simply cross-compile *sar*, rather the [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) suite of utilities which contains *sar* and other related commands.

Comment: Does it have an SNMP daemon?

Comment: I don't see anything running that matches "ps | grep -i snmp".

Comment: What device?  Does it have `ipkg`?  What distribution are you running?

Comment: Doesn't have ipkg either, I've added the O.S. version info to the question.

Comment: Adjacently-related: [Unix Stack Exchange: Determining the particular processor on which a process is running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330844/114401) <-- this answer works on embedded Linux with BusyBox, for this other problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/proc/loadavg` and `/proc/meminfo` should be available, so you could do

```
cat /proc/loadavg
cat /proc/meminfo
```

in a small script and process it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be doing what *sar* does, and was trying not to re-invent the wheel, however may end up doing that.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I've decided to parse the files myself and post their status to our Nagios server where it will graph the data for me.